# Make a POST request in JavaScript and load the returned page (Sinatra)

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, xmlhttprequest, sinatra

I am working on a website in which a user drags a file into a div, and the file is uploaded to a server running Sinatra through AJAX (XHR level 2). I want to get the response from Sinatra, as JSON, and then POST to another route with information from the JSON. This POST should result in another page being rendered.

I have got it to where I can upload the file, and get back a response. How would i do the rest?

P.S: I don't want to use GET, because some of the information shouldn't be in the URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your returning in the JSON? The HTML to be displayed, the URL of the content to load?

Comment: @JohnColvin I am returning whether or not the file uploaded successfully, and whether or not the name of the file is already in use.

Comment: Hmmm, that's pretty complicated. Why does the POST need to be involved? You could send back the URL to redirect to in the JSON and have javascript do the redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly the way you want. You would have to get the JSON data as string in subsequent POST call.
The idea is to create form element on the fly and use it to make subsequent POST call.

**javascript code**

```
$.post("/test1/frm", {param1 : "param"}, function(d){
  if(d.success) {
    // subsequent POST call on success use commented code in case subsequent request is XHR
    //$.post(d.url, d.response_data, function(dd){/*callback if any*/});
    var frm = $("<form method='POST'>").attr("action", d.url).append($("<input name='data'>").attr("value", JSON.stringify(d.response_data)));
    frm.submit();
  }
});
```

**controller code**

```
post :frm do
  logger.debug params.inspect
  content_type :json
  {:success => true, :url => "/test1/frm_post", :response_data => {:a => :b}}.to_json
end
post :frm_post do
  logger.debug params.inspect
  "success"
end
```

*Note* you would need to replace controller code with key - values with actual use case.